# get_option() filtering and getting out of recursion

Tags: filters, options

`get_option()` provides couple of filters `'pre_option_'.$option` and `'option_'.$option`.

However most times I tried to make use of these it usually explodes and not worth the trouble - either I need to check another option inside my filter, which triggers my filter, which triggers my filter...

Another common case is that I need to get current option that I am filtering and I cannot do that because I am filtering it.

Just curious - is there some practical logic to follow here? I know I could juggle my filter, but that is overhead that I don't like and filter removal is considered not too reliable by some. ;)

For recent practical example - I want to filter `posts_per_rss` to my option, but provide WordPress value if my option is not set (for the record I know that recommended way to mess with it is via `post_limits`).

Comment: You could use a static variable as a flag to control access to your filter function - or are you looking for a way to not trigger the filter at all?

Comment: @anu simply put I am looking for a way to circumvent recursion here without losing simplicity. I like to tinker robust and reusable extensions to native stuff for specific purposes.

Comment: @rarst Setting a flag could work then - don't think that adds too much complexity, although you would need to add a test at the start of your filter function, and set and unset the flag.

Comment: Aren't some options autoloaded? For the other cases i understand your problem and even after thinking about for an quarter hour, i have no idea how it's meant to be done in case you need another option. The @anu flag surely is an option, but i guess the `pre_option_.$option` filter is meant to completely override the db-query, so maybe the wp dev thought you will then just add multiple queries instead of the default one. Btw: I hope you don't mind - I slightly modified the Q. :)

Comment: @kaiser I don't think autoload affects retrieval process and filters, it merely pre-caches option. Option will still pass through filters, the only difference is that it will come from cache rather than database first time.

Comment: @Rarst - Meant you could fetch those first in some var (before filtering) and then reference it.

Comment: @kaiser that would work, but caching fallback value in advance kinda ruins it for me :) sorry to be picky... I just thought up multiple ways that would probably work, but most turn simple operation into cryptic mess or require such prep work which I don't really want to herd...

Comment: @Rarst - Beeing picky is ok. It's code :) And yes, I understand what your problem is. I yesterday tried to modify the output of the gallery shortcode (only the mark up) and that means writing the whole function from scratch (or repeating anything but 5 lines), because the only filters are a) a bypass at the beginning and b) the result. I'm just glad that i could get around the nav menu item problem with a pretty simple solution https://gist.github.com/960910 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually I remove the filter, then add it back on afterwards;

```
function _my_custom_option( $option )
{
    remove_filter( 'pre_option_name', '_my_custom_option' );

    // do what you like with $option

    add_filter( 'pre_option_name', '_my_custom_option' );
    return $option;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_name', '_my_custom_option' );
```

Comment: if i would've seen something like that outside the context of this discussion i wouldn't know what to think about it ... and likely have missunderstood it. At least add_filter just adds an array to an array, so i can be done and will work... +1 for beeing extremly tricky.